# Find the conditional density of $X_1$ given that it is not the smallest of the n values among n independent uniform $(0, 1)$ random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent uniform $(0, 1)$ random variables. Find the
conditional density of $X_1$ given that it is not the smallest of the $n$ values.

Here is my idea:

Let $Y$ denote that $X_1$ is not the smallest value

By intuition, $F_{X_1|Y}(x_1|y)=\frac{F_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot F_Y(y)}{F_Y(y)}=F_{X_1}(x_1)=\int_{0}^{x_1}1 \mathrm{d}x_1=x_1$

But I wonder if $Y$ and $X_1$ are independent and how to prove it strictly

Comment: You didn't introduce $X$.

Comment: @joriki Sorry and it should be $X_1$

Comment: $X_1$ is likely to be higher given $Y$ than when given *not* $Y$, so they are not independent

Comment: But if the smallest value is $z$ and not $X_1$ then I would have thought $X_1$ would be conditionally uniformly distributed between $z$ and $1$.  So to answer the question, you could integrate across the distribution of the smallest value.  As a check, if $n=2$ I would expect the resulting distribution to have density $2x_1$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for comment, and I wonder what is Pr($X_1$ is the smallest), is it $\frac1n$?

Comment: Yes.  The probability of ties is $0$ and so each $X_i$ has probability $\frac 1n$ of being the smallest

Comment: @Henry Does it look like that: I randomly pick n numbers between 0 and 1, and the probability of the first number is the smallest is $\frac1n$?

Comment: Yes - though the original question is conditioned on that not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=X_{(1)}$ be the minimum of the $X_i$. For $t\in(0,1)$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) &= 1-\mathbb P(Y > t)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i>t\} \right)\\
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb P(X_i>t)\\
&= 1- \mathbb P(X_1>t)^n\\
&= 1-(1-t)^n,
\end{align}
and so the density of $Y$ is $f_Y(t)=n(1-t)^{n-1}\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t)$.

Let $E=\{X_1=Y\}$, then the distribution of $X_1$ conditioned on $E$ is the same as the distribution of $Y$. By the law of total probability, we have for $t\in(0,1)$
$$
1 = f_{X_1}(t)
=f_{X_1}(t\mid E)\mathbb P(E) + f_{X_1}(t\mid E^c)\mathbb P(E^c) 
= f_{X_1}(t\mid E)\frac 1n +f_{X_1}(t\mid E^c)\frac{n-1}n.
$$
It follows that
$$
f_{X_1}(t\mid E^c) = \left(\frac n{n-1}\right)\left(1 - f_{X_1}(t\mid E)\frac1n \right)=\left(\frac n{n-1}\right) (1-(1-t)^{n-1})\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t).
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I wonder why $\mathbb P(E)= \frac 1n$, is it because $X_{i}$ are i.i.d?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i=Y)=1$ and $\mathbb P(X_i=Y)=\mathbb P(X_j=Y)$ for $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n$, so...

Comment: How to understand that $\mathbb P(X_i=Y)=\mathbb P(X_j=Y)$ because $X_i$ are all continuous, and the probability of getting any value between 0 and 1 is zero?

Comment: $\{X_i=Y\} = \bigcap_{j=1}^n \{X_i\leqslant X_j\}$ which certainly has positive probability...

Comment: I seem to understand! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=X_{(1)}$ denote the minimum of the $X_i$ , $E=\{X_1=Y\}$ denote the event that $X_1$ is the minimum among $\{X_i\}$

I am going to prove that $\mathbb P (E)=\frac {1}{n}$, similarly we can prove that the probability is the same for all $X_i$

Let $Z=X_{(1)}$ denote the minimum of the $X_2,X_3...X_n$, namely the rest $n-1$ r.v.

For $t\in(0,1)$, we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t) &= 1-(1-t)^{n-1}
\end{align}

So the density $f_Z(t)=(n-1)(1-t)^{n-2}(t)~~~~~~~~~t\in(0,1)$

We have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1~\rm is~the~minimum)&=\mathbb P(X_1\le Z)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb P(X_1\le t)\cdot f_Z(t) \mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}t\cdot (n-1)(1-t)^{n-2}(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1n
\end{align}

Similarly, we have $\mathbb P(X_i$ is the minimum$)=\frac 1n$ holds for all $i=1,2,...n$

Now I am going to show that $\mathbb P(X_i$ is the second minimum$)=\frac 1n, i=1,2,...n$

Take $X_1$ as an example, let $S$ denote the event: $X_1$ is the second minimum, $E_i, i=2,3,...n$ denote $X_i$ is the minimum, notice that:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S)&=\mathbb P(S|E_2)\mathbb P(E_2)+\mathbb P(S|E_3)\mathbb P(E_3)+...\mathbb P(S|E_n)\mathbb P(E_n)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\mathbb P(S|E_i)\mathbb P(E_i)
\end{align}

And we have:
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(S|E_i)= \mathbb P(X_1~{\rm is~the~minimum~among}~X_2,X_3,..X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...X_n)=\frac {1}{n-1}\\
&\mathbb P(E_i)=\frac 1n
\end{align}

So we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(S)&=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\mathbb P(S|E_i)\mathbb P(E_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac {1}{n-1}\cdot \frac1n\\
&=\frac 1n
\end{align}

So $\mathbb P(S)=\frac 1n$, and we can know that $\mathbb P(X_i$ is the second minimum$)=\frac 1n, i=1,2,...n$

Similarly, we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_i~{\rm is~the~third~minimum})=\cdots 
 \mathbb P(X_i~{\rm is~the~nth~minimum})=\frac 1n, i=1,2,...n
\end{align}

That is:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_i~{\rm is~the~k^{th}~minimum})=\frac 1n, i=1,2,...n,~k=1,2,\cdots n
\end{align}